# Круглые скобки в regex python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Прошу помощи у гуру python3.

Мне нужно с помощью модуля *re*, в частности с помощью **re.sub**,  в *python3* найти и изменить участок текста такого типа:

```
>A/text/text_date/text_text_text_124454_10-10_(Day_unknown)<
>A/text/text_date/text_text_text_12424544_10-10-date<
```

Как с помощью re.sub найти *(Day_unkonwn)* ? re.sub пропускает его, но с числовым значением все ОК, в текстовом редакторе sublime text тоже находится.
Пробовал данные выражение и их комбинации, просто игнор.

```
[\S][\w\S]*\<
[\-\_][\(\)A-Za-z0-9\_]*\<
```

Я думаю, проблема в скобках, но как их обойти я не знаю.

UPDATE для комментариев

Есть такая строка

> A/tashkent/roi595/2019_EDI_IML_337108_2019-01-14<

И такая

> A/Moscow/586/2019_EDI_IML_346030_2019-01_(Day_unknown)<

Вот строку вторую не находит мой скрипт.

```
re.findall(r'[ABC][\w\-\/]*\/[0-9]*\_[\w\_\-]*\-' + [0-9]* + r'[\S][\w\_\S]*<', text)
```

sublime text видит, а python нет.

Comment: Что нужно найти во второй строке? Всё, что в скобках, можно найти с помощью `\([^()]+\)`

Comment: Уточните суть вопроса, пожалуйста. Желательно привести несколько примеров с конкретными датами и то что вы хотите получить в результате - так гораздо проще понять ваши намерения

Comment: Есть такая строка
>A/tashkent/roi595/2019_EDI_IML_337108_2019-01-14<
И такая
>A/Moscow/586/2019_EDI_IML_346030_2019-01_(Day_unknown)<

Вот строку вторую не находит мой скрипт.  

re.findall(r'[ABC][\w\-\/]*\/[0-9]*\_[\w\_\-]*\-' + [0-9]* + r'[\S][\w\_\S]*<', text) 

sublime text видит, а python нет.

Comment: `r'[ABC][\w\-\/]*\/[0-9]*_[\w_\-]*\-' + [0-9]* + r'[\S][\w_\S]*<'` - здесь вы должны получить ошибку: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'`

Comment: Вы все таки пытаетесь искать текст или делать замену? Если делать замену, то приведите пример замены

Comment: [Находит ваша регулярка и первую, и вторую строку](https://regex101.com/r/6GQfrm/1).

Answer (score 1):

Пример поиска:

```
In [62]: text="""line 1
    ...: A/tashkent/roi595/2019_EDI_IML_337108_2019-01-14<
    ...: blah-blah-blah
    ...: A/Moscow/586/2019_EDI_IML_346030_2019-01_(Day_unknown)<"""
    ...:

In [63]: pat = r'([ABC]/[^/]*/[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*_)([^<\n\r]*)'

In [64]: re.findall(pat, text)
Out[64]:
[('A/tashkent/roi595/2019_EDI_IML_337108_', '2019-01-14'),
 ('A/Moscow/586/2019_EDI_IML_346030_', '2019-01_(Day_unknown)')]
```

или так:

```
In [65]: pat2 = r'([ABC]/[^/]*/(?:[^_]*_){4})([^<\n\r]*)'

In [66]: re.findall(pat2, text)
Out[66]:
[('A/tashkent/roi595/2019_EDI_IML_337108_', '2019-01-14'),
 ('A/Moscow/586/2019_EDI_IML_346030_', '2019-01_(Day_unknown)')]
```

---

пример замены:

текст до замены:

```
In [69]: print(text)
line 1
A/tashkent/roi595/2019_EDI_IML_337108_2019-01-14<
blah-blah-blah
A/Moscow/586/2019_EDI_IML_346030_2019-01_(Day_unknown)<
```

текст после замены:

```
In [70]: print(re.sub(pat2, r'\1date', text))
line 1
A/tashkent/roi595/2019_EDI_IML_337108_date<
blah-blah-blah
A/Moscow/586/2019_EDI_IML_346030_date<
```